# How can I align an edge with the other edges?

Tags: edit-mode

You can see the image here below where it has a red line, and this red line is the line I want to make sure all edges align with it perfectly. The 2 other edges align perfectly, but the other one seems to be off.

[image]

I tried making it align with the red line by just moving it, but it would always never be 100% accurate.

I have seen some topics having the same question, but I could not understand them clearly, if anyone could give a very detailed and easy to follow solution, it would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: select the verts, push *S, X* then 0 on the numpad.

Comment: It just brings me back to its original state. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can align the vertices of a mesh along an axis in the following way:

1. Mark the point you want to use as center
2. Place the *3D Cursor* there (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)
3. Switch *Transform Pivot Point* to *3D Cursor*
4. Mark the points you want to align
5. Press <kbd>S</kbd> for scale, then <kbd>X</kbd> for a specific axis and then the <kbd>0</kbd> key on the numeric keypad

This will scale the position of the selected vertices to the previously selected zero point, namely the *3D cursor* on the *X axis*.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Alternative answer:

Select Vertex mode under snapping.
[image]

In wireframe mode (<kbd>SHFT-Z</kbd>), box select the centre verts.
[image]

Hover the mouse over the top vert and hit <kbd>G</kbd>><kbd>X</kbd>. Then hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
[image]